# error in inserting to mysql by php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

i'm trying to insert to database and it gave me this :

> Error inserting You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ')' at line 3 something wrong in Database

```
public function set_Animal($Name,$Gender,$Allergie,$Age,$Weight,$Type_ID,$Owner_ID,$Colour){
    $Animal_Query= "INSERT INTO animal (Name,Gender,Allergie,Age,Weight,Type_ID,Owner_ID,Colour)
                    VALUES ($Name,$Gender,$Allergie,$Age,$Weight,$Type_ID,$Owner_ID,$Colour)";
    if(mysqli_query($this->conn,$Animal_Query)) {
        return true ;
    }
    else {
        echo "Error inserting ".mysqli_error($this->conn);
        return false ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to enclose columns that have character data types with single quotes? For example: `INSERT INTO animal (Name)
VALUES ('$Name')`

Comment: First of all try to use `prepared statement`. Right now your query is vulnerable to `sql injection`. and second, as @yogur mentioned, you have to enclose all your `string` parameters in  _single quotes_

Comment: guys i have try that ..and its not working either

Comment: and its really bother me cause i have 5 classes and its work Fine

Comment: You really should try `prepared statement`, because even if you enclose your `string` variables in the _single quotes_ but you have _single quotes_ in the text of your variable, then it will cause errors. If you are using `prepared statement` then please edit your post and add new code to your post so we can investigate the new code...

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work, you have to enclose columns that have character data types with single quotes. However, that is suspect to SQL injection. Use prepared statements instead.

Supposing that all columns are characters except age and weight are numbers:

**EDIT:** Added checking if `$conn->prepare` was successful.

```
public function set_Animal ($Name,$Gender,$Allergie,$Age,$Weight,$Type_ID,$Owner_ID,$Colour){

    $Animal_Query = "INSERT INTO animal (Name,Gender,Allergie,Age,Weight,Type_ID,Owner_ID,Colour) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($Animal_Query)){
        $stmt->bind_param("sssiisss", $Name, $Gender, $Allergie,$Age,$Weight,$Type_ID,$Owner_ID,$Colour);

        if($stmt->execute())
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    } else {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

The function `bind_param` binds the parameters to the SQL query. The "sssiisss" argument lists the types of data that the parameters are. The s character tells mysql that the parameter is a string, while the i tells it that its a number.

The argument may be one of four types:

i : integer

d : double

s : string

b : BLOB

We should have one of these for each parameter.

Comment: I got these error when i apply your advice 
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: @IbrahemJadllah It seems there is a syntax error on your SQL query. Thus, `$conn->prepare` failed, and the parameters could not be binded.

Comment: @IbrahemJadllah Edited the code to check the success of preparing the statement

Comment: I have written a Class for this https://github.com/DennisWeidmann/SQLContentProvider